# Argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"

Tags: c++, char, undefined, constants, string-literals

I'm trying to join "ip-api.com/json/" and declared char "ip_address"
but "ip-api.com/json/" is underlined red and says:

```
argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"
```

How can it be done?

```
TCHAR path[_MAX_PATH];
        _tcscpy(path, ip_address);
        _tcscat("ip-api.com/json/", ip_address);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? `_tcscat("ip-api.com/json/", ip_address);` is trying to add the contents of `ip_address` to `"ip-api.com/json/"`.  You can't do that.

Comment: Remember that the `strcat` function (and relatives like the `_tcscat` function) have their destination as the first argument. Also remember that in C++ all literal strings are really ***constant*** arrays of characters. How can you concatenate to a constant array?

Comment: Yes, ip-api.com/json/ + ip_address. Why I can't?

Comment: @prako2 How would you access it?  `"ip-api.com/json/"` is a string literal.  You can't "reuse" it.

Comment: Maybe you wanted `_tcscat(path,"ip-api.com/json/");` or is `"ip-api.com/json/"` supposed to be at the beginning of the string?

Comment: *How can it be done?* -- By using string classes and have the class do the work for you, without error.

Comment: For more complex string formatting, why not use `std::snprintf`, or (even better, IMO) C++ string streams?

Comment: `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> TCHARString;`. Then when you use `TCHARString`, you have all the operations available for string classes, such as concatenation using `operator +`, `operator +=` etc, all without you having to ensure you have enough space, string literal issues, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this call

```
_tcscat("ip-api.com/json/", ip_address);
```

you are trying to modify a string literal.

String literals in C++ have types of constant character arrays. So converted to pointers they have the type `const char *`.

You may not change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

Moreover you have to reserve memory large enough to append the string pointed to by `ip_address` to another string in a character array.

For example

```
char address[_MAX_PATH] = "ip-api.com/json/";
_tcscat( address, ip_address);
```

Comment: Thank you! Still difficult to understand, but I got what I wanted.

Comment: @prako2 String literals are usually stored in a literal pool. For example string literals "A" and "B" can be stores in the pool like { 'A', '\0', 'B','\0' }. So if it was allowed to change string literals you would overwrite the memory occupied by string literals. And for example this statement if ( strcmp( s, "B" ) == 0 ) would be invalid. The string literal was already changed!